# K-th smallest quick sort python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, quicksort

I have to get K-th smallest element in unsorted array.
Not to sort the whole array I am trying only sort the subarrays that include K-th element. Then I am printing all K-th from 0 to len(array)

```
array = [6,5,4,3,2,1]
def quick_sort(lst, k):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    else:
        p = (lst[0] + lst[len(lst)-1])/2
        left = [x for x in lst if x <= p]
        right = [x for x in lst if x > p]
        
        if  k > len(left) -1 :
            k = k - len(left)+1
            return quick_sort(right,k)
        else:
            return quick_sort(left, k)
  
for i in range(len(array)):    
    print(*quick_sort(array,i+1))
```

I want to get 1,2,3,4,5,6
but my code does 2,3,5,6,6,6.
What I need to change?

P.S. THe main idea is not sorting all arrays and not using python sort functions

Comment: That's quickselect, not quicksort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array = [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

def quick_sort(lst, k):
    if len(lst) <= 1:
        return lst
    else:
        p = (lst[0] + lst[-1]) / 2
        left = [x for x in lst if x <= p]
        right = [x for x in lst if x > p]

        if k > len(left):
            k = k - len(left)
            return quick_sort(right, k)
        else:
            return quick_sort(left, k)

for i in range(len(array)):
    print(*quick_sort(array, i + 1))
```

Comment: Hello @Krzysiek Welcome to SO. It is always better to provide necessary information with your answer like, how your answer solves the question and what is the source of your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Just fixed the mistakes in lines 9-10

Comment: thank you. it works) 
But unfortunately it didnt help:( I get a time error 
Is there ways to increase speed? .
for example: maybe add middle subb_array ?
left = [x for x in lst if x < p], 
middle = [x for x in lst if x == p] 
right = [x for x in lst if x > p]